# In multi-cluster kubernetes environment, is it possible to mount a volume for specific nodes, such as nodes with specific labels?

Tags: kubernetes

We have multiple clusters for different apps. There is an agent, which run as an independent pod in a different namespace, which reads specific volumes with hostpath from each node on every cluster.  The agent uses these volumes to read the data. However certain volumes are not mounted on all nodes. Is there a way we can tell the agent to read volumes from a node with specific labels or use some kind of affinity rule where a specific pod is running? AFAIK, affinity rules work only for pods. Any suggestions would be much appreciated. TIA.

Tried affinity rules, but since they work only at pod level, the agent is limited in deployment across nodes.

Answer (score 0):

A setup where you need to read "from a `hostPath` on every node" best matches a Kubernetes [DaemonSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/daemonset/), which creates a new Pod on every node.  (A DaemonSet is pretty much the only place you should consider `hostPath`-type volumes, and "as a management agent" is a pretty typical use for this.)

Furthermore, a DaemonSet supports a node selector to [run only on specific nodes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/daemonset/#running-pods-on-select-nodes).

You can put these together to get a setup like:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet          # <--
metadata: { ... }
spec:
  selector: { ... }
  template:
    metadata: { ... }
    spec:
      nodeSelector:      # <--
        labelKey: value  # matches Node's `metadata: { labels: }`
      volumes:
        - name: agentdata
          hostPath:
            path: /var/log/agent
      containers:
        - name: agent
          image: registry.example.com/agent:20230329
          volumeMounts:
            - name: agentdata
              mountPath: /agent/data
```

This will run a separate Pod on each node.  If you need to aggregate the data, you could launch some sort of message-queueing system like Kafka or RabbitMQ in its own container (with a StatefulSet/Service) and have the collectors send data there, and then run an aggregator in its own Deployment that reads back the data.

Comment: Thanks @David. This solution partially meets the requirement in the sense that the agent will deploy on the nodes with specific labels. However, the agent needs to be deployed on ALL nodes. The agent reads from multiple volumes. Many of the volumes exist on all nodes. But there is one volume which exists only on specific nodes and therefore in volume section, would like to add something similar to node selector. Does not have to be a node selector. Can also leverage pod labels. But the filter has to be at volume level.